# Smooth scroll to multiple elements in horizontal div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one horizontal div and am trying to scroll to different elements based on id on click.

[JS Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6b7aq8gp/6/)

Here are the two main functions I tried:

```
function scroll1() {
/*   Attempt 1 */
    $('#scroll-post-1').scrollTo('#2')
}

function scroll2() {
/*  Attempt2 */
  $('#scroll-post-1').stop().animate({
    scrollLeft: $('#3').offset().left
  }, 500);
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

See the second attempt in action here:

```js
function scroll1() {
 $('#scroll-post-1').stop().animate({
  scrollLeft: $('#2').offset().left
 }, 500);
 event.preventDefault();
}

function scroll2() {
 $('#scroll-post-1').stop().animate({
  scrollLeft: $('#3').offset().left
 }, 500);
 event.preventDefault();
}

function scroll3() {
 $('#scroll-post-1').stop().animate({
  scrollLeft: $('#4').offset().left
 }, 500);
 event.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
.scroll-post {
  height: auto;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.mydiv {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 5em;
  width: auto;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-scrollTo/2.1.2/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="scroll-post" id="scroll-post-1">
      <div class="mydiv" id="1" onclick="scroll1();">Start Here</div>
      <div class="mydiv" id="2" onclick="scroll2();">Scroll Here</div>
      <div class="mydiv" id="3" onclick="scroll3();">Then Here</div>
      <div class="mydiv" id="4">Finally Here</div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

I've tried the `$(container).scrollTo(target)` method without any luck.
It works for the first element, but not any of the subsequent elements.

Comment: jsFiddle defaults to using window.onload = function(){} to wrap your code. As a result, your inlined event handlers cannot call the function. If you change it to no wrap, in `<head>` your scrolling clearly works, ish. Some work to do on the third and fourth handler, but it does scroll.

Comment: I just didn't save it with that setting. It's updated now. Yes, it works for the first element. My question is how to get it to work for subsequent elements in the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `.left` offset that jQuery was tracking was relative to the container, so it degraded as the element moved.

A better way would be to use the native JavaScript property for the element, [`offsetLeft`<sup>**MDN**</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft).

For example:

```
scrollLeft: $('#3')[0].offsetLeft
```

Full Demo of your code with `offsetLeft`: https://jsfiddle.net/5umvne08/

Comment: Works prefectly. BIG Thank you